# How to have Color code in sharepoint calender

Tags: sharepoint-2010

How to Color code  SharePoint calendar based on custom department column(which is a look up field appearing as drop down in new form)

1.i have a department list having two columns named department and color, where i have added  department name and also a color to each department.

2.and requirement is that the calender should be colored on the basis of department color defined.

Answer (score 0):

Try calendar overlays senario and will fit into this.